# Inserting data in multiple tables using Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I have 4 tables say, table1, table2, table3 and table4, which are interrelated.
Table1 will generate a primary key, that will be used in rest of the tables as reference key.

I have to insert multiple records in table 4 using this primary key. 
Since the requirement is the transaction should either commit successfully or it should rollback all the changes. That is the reason I thought of writing this in stored procedure. 
But got stuck, when I had to pass multiple rows data for table4.

Can anyone please suggest, how can I achieve this?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: is your primarykey autoincremented?

Comment: Yes, for all the tables, primary key will be auto incremented.

Answer (score 2):

i guess you want to do something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc
(
 invId IN NUMBER,
 cusId IN NUMBER
)
IS
    temp_id  NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO myTable (INV_ID) 
    VALUES (invId)
    returning id into temp_id;

    INSERT INTO anotherTable (ID, custID) 
    VALUES (temp_id, custId);  
END myproc;
```

Comment: Yes, right. This will work for first 3 tables, where I have to insert single records. But for 4th table I have to insert multiple records. I don't know how can I achieve that.

Comment: i guess you already have the multiple values in parameters of stored procedure. you just have to use temp_id valriable. i will not lose values till stored procedure ends.

Comment: No. of parameters of stored procedure will be equal to the no. of columns of all the tables. But in case of 4th table where I have to insert multiple rows, the no. of values can not be fixed.

Comment: if you please post the current stored procudure you are using for inserting in 4th table

Comment: I have not written any procedure to insert data in 4th table yet.

Comment: put table4 in separate SP and loop it from code to insert many rows in 4th SP. or define as many parameters for rows to insert in first SP and check for nulls.